# Delete object on s3 using url link in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

Using c# in asp.net mvc, I try to delete a lot of images from S3 buckets with different naming schemas. Is it possible to delete image using its URL?

Something like:

```
   client.DeleteObject(URL);
```

Comment: Well yes. the s3 sdk doesn't provide you with this, but underneath it all they simply parse the bucket name to be the host and the object path to be the key, see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html

So you could write a little helper method to parse URLs and use the existing `key, bucket` method on s3 client (unless you want to roll your own authentication which is meh...)

Comment: to @zaitsman Please, if you could, add an example of parsing  the bucket name and Key as an answer and I will click on it as useful

Answer (score 0):

```
            var client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        DeleteObjectRequest request = new DeleteObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = _amazonS3BucketName,
            Key = _amazonS3PathAfterBucketName
        };
        var response = client.DeleteObject(request);
```